# how can we use the timer in thread to create the text file after specific periofd of time using vc++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, timer

I have tried this code to generate the same text file after every minute, but it is not working on console application. I am using vs2017

```
 void CALLBACK f(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
 {
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("C:\\log.txt", ios::app);
myfile <<  " : test" << "\n";
myfile.close();
KillTimer(hwnd, timerId);
}
unsigned int __stdcall mythread(void* data)
{
while (startii == 0)
{
    SetTimer(0,             // handle to main window 
        0,            // timer identifier 
        10000,                 // 10-second interval 
        (TIMERPROC)&f);     // no timer callback 

    return 0;
  }
 int main()
{
myhandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythread, 0, 0, 0);
}enter code here
```

Comment: The `main` function you show returns immediately once you've created the thread. That ends the whole process and all threads running in it.

Comment: Also remember that timers needs a window event loop (even for window-less applications) to be processed. Without the normal window even loop you won't be receiving any timer events. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) behavior.

Comment: hi @SomeprogrammerdudeI have also tried it with
     `code`  
         int main()
                  {
     while(1)
    {
      myhandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythread, 0, 0, 0);
      }
       }
could you please share any example of the same how to do that ?

Comment: and also tried as
 int main()
{
myhandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythread, 0, 0, 0);
while(1)
{}
}

Comment: The first variant is really bad as it creates new threads in infinity. Neither examples have the event loop needed. Which needs to be inside the thread itself.

Answer (score 0):

use `std::thread` and           `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(7000))` or so.

thread itself will look like that

```
UINT CALLBACK hammersmith(VOID *c)
{   
    while (1)
    {   
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lb(com_m);
        sp_tray = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(7));
        com_r = sp_tray;
        lb.unlock();    
        sp_tray.reset();
    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

or use similar thread function with `_beginthreadex` . And you can use winapi's `Sleep()` .   And `CALLBACK` includes stdcall stuff so use it instead.
timers are from  16-bit windows era